# Freeform Composer return path

Tags: solspace-freeform, composer

How do I inject the Return Path into my Freeform Composer template, so it directs people to the specified page, after submitting the form?

```
{exp:freeform:composer form_id="{form-freeform:form_id}" composer_template_id="{form-freeform:composer_template_id}" return="?????????" form:class="pure-form pure-form-aligned"}
    {composer:page}
        {composer:rows}
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                {composer:columns}
                {if composer:field_total == 0}{/if}
                {composer:fields}
                    {if composer:field_label}       {!-- Output field labels --}
                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if captcha}<p>{composer:field_label}</p>{/if}
                        {if:else}
                            <label {if composer:field_name != ''}for="{composer:field_name}"{/if}>{freeform:description:{composer:field_name}}</label>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                    {if composer:field_output}      {!-- Output field inputs --}
                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_title'}
                            <h4>
                                {if composer:field_name AND composer:field_required}{freeform:field:{composer:field_name} attr:required="required" attr:placeholder="Required"}
                                {if:else}{composer:field_output}
                                {/if}
                            </h4>
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if captcha}{captcha}<br /><input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px">{/if}
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'nonfield_submit'}
                            <div class="pure-controls"><button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Submit</button></div>
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'checkbox_group'}
                            <div style="display:inline-block">{composer:field_output}</div>
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'radio'}
                            <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">{composer:field_output}</div>
                        {if:else}
                            {if composer:field_name AND composer:field_required}
                                {freeform:field:{composer:field_name} attr:required="required" attr:placeholder="Required"}
                            {if:else}
                                {composer:field_output}
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                {/composer:fields}
                {/composer:columns}
            </div>
        {/composer:rows}
    {/composer:page}
{/exp:freeform:composer}
```

[image: Return Path definition in EE Edit Entry]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can just leave off the return parameter and it will take the value you put into the channel field

Comment: I've tried this, but it just sends me back to the empty form page when I submit the form (it says it'll do this in the Docs as well).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the fieldtype you don't need to use the entire {exp:freeform:composer} tag set. Just the field name as normal: {form-freeform} and everything else is automatic.

Comment: I have a load of styling stuff which is why I'm output the full Composer tag.

Comment: You can create a **custom Composer Template** in the Freeform CP with your formatting and associate that custom template with your Composer form when editing the Composer form in the CP (i.e. the section where you're visually adding/removing fields and columns/rows: there's a dropdown in the top-left to select your custom Composer Template).